# Setting up page reload with Facebook Pixel after cookie agreement

Tags: javascript, facebook, reload

I've got this code for cookie agreement:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var cookieState = Cookies.get('fbAllowed');

if (cookieState == null) {
    $('#fbCookie').fadeIn(1000);
}
else {
    document.getElementById("fbCookie").style.display = "none";
} 


$('#agree').click(function() {
    Cookies.set('fbAllowed', '1', { expires: 3650, path: '/'});
    $('#fbCookie').fadeOut(1000);
    window.location.reload(true);

    $('#disagree').click(function() {
        Cookies.set('fbAllowed', '2', { expires: 3650, path: '/'});
        $('#fbCookie').fadeOut(1000); 
     });
```

});

With the reload the Facebook Pixel script should be included in head

```
    <script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
   n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
   n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=
   [];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
   t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}
    (window,
    document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', 'XYZ'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
    </script>
   <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XYZ&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
    /></noscript>
```

Due to German legislation the pixel code should only be set after user's agreement.

How can I implement this?
Thanks for any help!
alexinge

Comment: Well check if the cookie is set before you output that code …?

Comment: Hello! The cookie check and cookie set works, but I don't know how to inlude the facebook pixel script with reload!

Comment: Do you have any server-side programming language involved here, or is this all purely client-side?

Comment: It's a typo3 installation...

Comment: Then it would probably make sense to do the cookie check in some central controller, and set a variable there that you can refer to in the respective template where this code is output ...

Comment: No javascript solution possible?

Comment: Well you could try and just write out the whole code block using `document.write` ... but then you would have to do it as the page is loading, if you do it at a later point, it will replace the whole document.

Comment: I've tried a lot with append / appendChild. I do not find a solution. Could you post some code with document.write?